# Google Map API v3 Infowindow doesn't show up on mouseover/click on a polygon

Tags: google-maps-api-3, infowindow, polygons

I am trying to display dynamic data in infowindows whenever user hovers over polygons on the map. Debugging shows the data and other infowindow/polygon settings are all right. I am able to get the color change on mouseover, just that infowindows doesn't show up. What might be the reason behind it? What am I missing here?

```
statePolygon = new google.maps.Polygon({
    paths: stateBorderCoords,
    strokeColor: '#f33f00', 
    strokeOpacity: 1, 
    strokeWeight: 1,
    fillColor: '#ff0000', 
    fillOpacity: 0.2
});

statePolygon.pId = infoText; // Fetching from a JSON response
statePolygon.wPet = wPet;    // Fetching from a JSON response
statePolygon.infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

google.maps.event.addListener(statePolygon,"mouseover",function(event){
    this.setOptions({fillColor: "#00FF00"});
    this.infoWindow.setPosition(event.latLng);
    this.infoWindow.setContent(this.wPet);
    this.infoWindow.open(map, this);
});

google.maps.event.addListener(statePolygon,"mouseout",function(){
    this.setOptions({fillColor: "#FF0000"});
    this.infoWindow.close();
});

google.maps.event.addListener(statePolygon, 'click', function(){
    //createInfoWindow(this.pId);
});

statePolygon.setMap(map);
```

Comment: `createInfoWindow()` would appear to be important. Could you add the definition of that function, please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What happens if you leave out the "this" in the line:

```
this.infoWindow.open(map, this);
```

?

I've been fighting with something similar over the last few days and just discovered my code works for google.maps.Markers (as in Google pins) but not for google.maps.Circles (and I guess google.maps.Polygons.)

My guess: "infoWindow.open(map, object)" which tries to anchor the InfoWindow to the *object* only seems to work for google.maps.Markers, not Circles, Polygons, etc. What does seem to work is "open(map)" which doesn't anchor it to anything. However the position of the infoWindow has to be explicitly set (which you are already doing).

**Edit:**

In my case this doesn't work (assuming global variable map)

```
var circle = { clickable: true,
               strokeColor: "darkred",
               strokeOpacity: 1,
               strokeWeight: 1,
               fillColor: "green",
               fillOpacity: 1,
               map: map,
               center: new google.maps.LatLng(55.95,-3.19),
               radius: 45
            };
var marker1 = new google.maps.Circle(circle);

infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
infoWindow.setContent("Hello");
inoWindow.setPosition(new google.maps.LatLng(55.95,-3.19));
infoWindow.open(map,marker1);
```

but this does:

```
var circle = { clickable: true,
               strokeColor: "darkred",
               strokeOpacity: 1,
               strokeWeight: 1,
               fillColor: "green",
               fillOpacity: 1,
               map: map,
               center: new google.maps.LatLng(55.95,-3.19),
               radius: 45
            };
var marker1 = new google.maps.Circle(circle);

infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
infoWindow.setContent("Hello");
infoWindow.setPosition(new google.maps.LatLng(55.95,-3.19));
infoWindow.open(map);
```

**The only difference is in the last line.**

Thinking about the above post, setting the position after opening presumably overwrites the anchor position and thus makes it appear.

Comment: It's possible that the function `createInfoWindow()` adds an infoWindow to the polygon. That could make `this.infoWindow` valid, which is why I asked about it. But you're right: normally polygons don't have that.

Comment: Hi Andrew, add a field infoWindow to a polygon make the code valid but in my experience even then the infoWindow remains stubbornly invisible, or off screen/map ...

Comment: Doh! google.maps.Circle and google.maps.Polygon don't have a method *getPosition()* or a property *position* where as google.maps.Marker does. So my updated guess is that using infoWindow.open(map,object) results in the infoWindow position being undefined and hence no show.

Answer (score 0):

First you open the InfoWindow, then set its position:

http://jsfiddle.net/fuDfa/

```
google.maps.event.addListener(statePolygon,"mouseover",function(event){
    this.setOptions({fillColor: "#00FF00"});
    this.infoWindow.setContent(this.wPet);
    this.infoWindow.open(map);
    this.infoWindow.setPosition(event.latLng);
});
```

However, I realized that if the mouse moves on top of the InfoWindow (even if it's on top of the polygon), it will count as if the mouse moved outside the polygon. So, the polygon will turn red and Infowindow will close. But since the mouse is still inside the polygon, the infowindow will open again, causing a flicker.

I don't know a way to get around this (tried a timeout but it's not reliable either). I only thought about putting the Infowindow in a preset position instead of event.latLng.

Comment: Agree. This works but only issue is if the mouse is pointed on the borders of the polygon there is a continuous flicker. Anyways thanks. Atleast I have a starting point to work further on this.

Comment: I'm using this same method and coming across the 'flicker' problem as well. If anyone has a solution, it'd be great to hear it.